# Getting java.util.ConcurrentModificationException while looping through ArrayList

Tags: java, spring-boot, for-loop, jpa, arraylist

I am developing an application using Spring Boot as a backend. While looping through and updating a value of an object from a Array list throwing below error,

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:911) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:861) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$IteratorProxy.next(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:883) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
```

I have changed the loop like below,

```
for(Object obj : myObjectList) {
   obj.setEndDate(someDate);
   obj.isActive(false);
   objectRepository.save(obj);
}
```

And

```
Iterator<Object> objIterator = myObjectList.iterator();
   while(objIterator.hasNext()) {
      Object obj = objIterator.next();
      obj.setEndDate(someDate);
      obj.isActive(false);
      objectRepository.save(obj);
   }
```

Both are throwing the same error.

While printing a log into these for loops. It will be printing the log for the first time and throwing the error on the second iteration.

Comment: What does `objectRepository.save(object)` do? If that also changes the list, then the exception will be thrown.

Comment: What is `object` ? I assume `objectRepository.save(object);` as `objectRepository.save(obj);`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that @GauthamM .

Comment: Is this application multithreaded? Could some other thread be modifying `myObjectList` while you're iterating over it?

Comment: is there no stacktrace?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to modify a list whilst iterating over it, switching to using an Iterator was the right call, however you need a while loop rather than a for loop:

```
List<Object> myObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<Object> objIterator = myObjectList.iterator();
    while (objIterator.hasNext()) {
        Object obj = objIterator.next();
        obj.setEndDate(someDate);
        obj.isActive(false);
        objectRepository.save(obj);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use fail-safe interaction by creating new ArrayList wrapper like that:

```
for(Object obj : new ArrayList<>(myObjectList)) {
   obj.setEndDate(someDate);
   obj.isActive(false);
   objectRepository.save(obj);
}
```

It'll resolve your problem

Answer (score 2):

Complementing the other answers, you could modify your collection first and then save it.

```
    myObjectList.forEach(obj -> {
        obj.setEndDate(someDate);
        obj.isActive(false);
    });
    objectRepository.save(myObjectList); //Depending of your version, this method could be saveAll();
```